# Combine the array of strings in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, recursion, cartesian-product

I have:

```
TEXT='1,2
a,b,c
XX,YY'
```

I need the output like this:

```
OUT='1,a,XX
1,a,YY
1,b,XX
1,b,YY
1,c,XX
1,c,YY
2,a,XX
2,a,YY
2,b,XX
2,b,YY
2,c,XX
2,c,YY'
```

Should be some recursion, because the length of lines and lines count is unknown. Explanation would be great, but just the code is also OK.

What I have done so far (trying to use arrays):

```
TEXT='1,2
a,b,c
XX,YY'

declare -a lines

COUNT=0

while read LINE; do
    lines[$COUNT]=$LINE
    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
done <<<"$TEXT"

declare -A A

K1_MAX=0
K2_MAX=0

for key in "${!lines[@]}"; do
    IFS=',' read -ra symbols <<<"${lines[$key]}"
    for key2 in "${!symbols[@]}"; do
        if [[ $key -gt $K1_MAX ]]; then K1_MAX=$key; fi
        if [[ $key2 -gt $K2_MAX ]]; then K2_MAX=$key2; fi
        A[$key $key2]=${symbols[$key2]}
    done
done

for key in "${!A[@]}"; do
    echo $key: "${A[$key]}"
true
done | sort
```

This gives me the output:

```
0 0: 1
0 1: 2
1 0: a
1 1: b
1 2: c
2 0: XX
2 1: YY
```

But still can't understand how to combine those values between themselves.

Comment: This is a PITA in bash because it doesn't have nested arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TEXT='1,2
a,\n,c
p ,,q

XX,YY'

buildstr(){
    local prefix="$1"

    if [ $# = 1 ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$prefix"
    else
        IFS=, read -r -a a <<<"$2,"
        shift 2
        for i in "${a[@]}"; do
            buildstr "${prefix:+$prefix,}$i" "$@"
        done
    fi
}

readarray -t a <<<"$TEXT"

OUT=$(buildstr "" "${a[@]}")

declare -p OUT
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using brace expansion and `eval` (aka evil) might be:

```
eval printf -v OUT "%s\\\n" {${TEXT//$'\n'/'},{'}}
OUT=${OUT%?} # to strip off the trailing newline character
OUT=${OUT//[\{\}]} # remove '{' and '}' characters, if any
echo "OUT='$OUT'"
```

or, by the same token, using an array:

```
eval arr=({${TEXT//$'\n'/'},{'}})
OUT="${arr[*]}"
OUT=${OUT// /$'\n'}
OUT=${OUT//[\{\}]}
```

Comment: That is so cool. Just `eval printf "%s\\\n" {${TEXT//$'\n'/'},{'}}`

Comment: Looks nice, but produces wrong output if the line contains only one symbol.

Comment: @RomanDobra You're right. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` using a recursive function call:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }

      { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            val[NR,i]=$i              # val[row#][element#]=elementVal
            max[NR]=NF                # number of elements in a row
        }
      }

function print_tuples(row, out, i) {

    if (row > NR)
        print out
    else
        for (i=1;i<=max[row];i++)
            print_tuples(row+1, out (out ? OFS : "") val[row,i])
}

END   { print_tuples(1) }
' <<< "${TEXT}"
```

This generates:

```
1,a,XX
1,a,YY
1,b,XX
1,b,YY
1,c,XX
1,c,YY
2,a,XX
2,a,YY
2,b,XX
2,b,YY
2,c,XX
2,c,YY
```

Storing in `bash` variable `OUT`:

```
$ OUT=$(awk '... see code above ...')
$ typeset -p OUT
declare -- OUT="1,a,XX
1,a,YY
1,b,XX
1,b,YY
1,c,XX
1,c,YY
2,a,XX
2,a,YY
2,b,XX
2,b,YY
2,c,XX
2,c,YY"
```

Comment: It's slightly more efficient to move the `max[NR]=NF` out of the loop. Also to handle lines containing a single zero-length value, you could use `max[NR]=(NF?NF:1)`. Consider: `TEXT=$(printf "0,1\na\nx,y\n")` vs `TEXT=$(printf "0,1\n\nx,y\n")`

Answer (score 0):

This is simply bash-syntax:

```
echo -e {1,2}","{a..c}","{XX,YY}"\n"
1,a,XX
 1,a,YY
 1,b,XX
 1,b,YY
 1,c,XX
 1,c,YY
 2,a,XX
 2,a,YY
 2,b,XX
 2,b,YY
 2,c,XX
 2,c,YY
```

Note that you can't replace values in curly braces with variables, because brace expansion happens before variable substitution.

The .. - syntax is just a from-to and would have worked for 1,2 too, but is one additional character.

you may as well use multi digit numbers, backwards runs, leading zeros and steps different from one:

```
echo -e {9..11}","{c..a}","{099..101..2}"\n"
9,c,099
 9,c,101
 9,b,099
 9,b,101
 9,a,099
 9,a,101
 10,c,099
 10,c,101
 10,b,099
 10,b,101
 10,a,099
 10,a,101
 11,c,099
 11,c,101
 11,b,099
 11,b,101
 11,a,099
 11,a,101
```

Very powerful.